# "Safe" handling of a Mutex?

Tags: c#, mutex, memory-mapped-files

I'm constantly reading from a memory mapped file another process is writing to and use a mutex to synchronize this operation. In my few tests so far this works just fine, but... what if my application crashes right after acquiring the mutex and before releasing it? Is there any way to guarantee a release of the mutex, even in case of such a crash?

Also how would I handle a crash of the other process, which might not have released the mutex yet? Do I need to handle AbandonedMutexException each time I call mutex.WaitOne()?

Right now I'm doing it similar to this:

```
public MyState GetState()
{
    MyState state = new State();
    this._mutex.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        state.X = this._mmView.ReadSingle(0);
        state.Y = this._mmView.ReadSingle(4);
        [..]
    }
    finally
    {
        this._mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
    return state;
}
```

**_mmView** is a MemoryMappedViewAccessor I instantiated before. This whole method **GetState()** gets called each frame as part of a game loop, so about every few milliseconds.

PS: Also, is there any other obvious problem why this could fail, that I didn't already mention?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eugen's answer is correct -- the operating system will release the mutex for you. Now think hard about what the consequences of this fact are:

- You took out the mutex to ensure that no one would mutate state while you were reading, or read state while you were mutating. Let's suppose the latter.
- Another application wants to read the state, so it tries to take the mutex. It is forced to wait.
- You mutated some state and then crashed.
- The operating system released the mutex.
- The other application now immediately acquires the mutex, **and is now effectively reading state "while" another process is mutating it**. The fact that the other process is now dead and gone means that the bogus state will now last *forever*, and the reading process will probably itself crash and die horribly. **You have just defeated the safety system provided by the mutex**.

In short, you are worrying about exactly the wrong thing. You shouldn't be worried about *what happens if my mutex **never** gets released.* The worst thing that happens then is everyone waits forever, which is sad, but eventually the user will reboot the machine. You should be worried about *what happens if mutex **does** get released because I crashed halfway through a mutation*. In that scenario *processes will now probably be crashing all over the place and the user's data will be permanently corrupted*.

Don't get into that situation in the first place. The solution to the problem is **do not crash when you have taken out a mutex for writing**. If you don't write programs that crash then you don't have to worry about it, because its not going to happen. So **just don't write programs that ever crash.**

Comment: "don't write programs that ever crash", or, as the Zen master said - "Avoid Error." Great advice. ahem.

Comment: Doesn't sound very robust nor realistic, though. What if the user simply kills the process through task manager, forcibly crashing the app?

Comment: @Mario: I don't know what you think is unrealistic; I assure you that these sorts of data corruption bugs crop up frequently and must be protected against if you care about the state of the user's data. Re: what if the user crashes the app? You're asking me what happens when the user does stuff that corrupts their own data? **Their data gets corrupted**, that's what. Users that don't want their data to be corrupted **ought not to be taking down their apps**. There's a *reason* why doing so puts up a dialog box that says "you might corrupt your data if you do this".

Comment: I'm with you on carefully taking measures to ensure data integrity, but writing bug-free software that never crashes sounds like a pretty **hard** goal to me. There's always going to be the one obscure error where you didn't think anything could ever happen, right? Anyway, I'm not mutating state in this case - that's the other process' responsibility and thus out of my reach.

Comment: @EricLippert I don't understand. Never releasing is in the exact same boat as releasing on crash. When the user reboots, the data is still just as corrupt. Same worry either way.

Comment: @jnm2: That's correct. I don't understand what you don't understand. My advice was not "the operating system should do a better job of keeping mutexes of crashed programs around". My advice was "don't write programs that crash while data is corrupted".

Comment: Just saying the second to last paragraph is confusing. There's no reason to *not* be worried about a never-released mutex but to be *more* worried about a crash-released mutex, since the data corruption is the same.

Answer (score 2):

When a process ends while owning a mutex, the OS will automatically release the mutex for you. Try this out by aquiring the mutex and then `raise new WhateverException()` - the other process will carry on.

The same is true for all sync primitives AFAIK