# Access to .txt [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net

I've developed a multi-user application. One user saves a string to a text file, other users have to read this string in a background process.

My problem is: when some users open the file to read the string, another user that wants  to save a new string can't write to the file. I would like to implement a system that checks if the file is opened or not, and in case it is, waits a few seconds and retries.

What is the function or command to look if the file is already opened?

Comment: Don't open file as exclusive. Open it as shared. So it would be possible for file to be opened by multiple instances at the same time.

Comment: Tanks, you suggested me the right way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few patterns you can deal with. Two I'd recommend would be:

- [Dealing with `FileAccess`, `FileMode` and `FileShare`](https://varunvns.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/reading-and-writing-in-text-files-with-multiple-programs-accessing-it-simultaneously/)
- [Sync the file access with `EventWaitHandle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690537/multi-processes-readwrite-one-file)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using tips:

i've replaced this code:

```
         ip_acquisito = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(path_elenco & "\ip.txt")
```

with this code:

```
     Using fs As FileStream = File.Open(path_elenco & "\ip.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
             Dim b(1024) As Byte
             Dim temp As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding(True)

             Do While fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0
                 ip_acquisito = temp.GetString(b)
             Loop
     End Using
```